# Magento 2: How to set catalog product description input field using WYSIWYG instead of page builder?

Tags: magento2, product, layout, adminhtml, page-builder

After i upgrade my Magento version to 2.4.3, the product description input field in backend becomes page builder input field, i want to revert it back using the regular wyiswyg input field without disabling the page builder from Store > COnfiguration, how can i achieve this ?

From this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

Comment: you have disable the page builder from store >> configuration >> Content Management >> Advanced Content Tools >> Enable Page Builder to NO.

If you need Enable the page builder then customization for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this quite easily for product descriptions via the stores > product >attribute menu - you can revert the description attribute back to "Text Editor" under Attribute Properties there is a drop down "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner".

[image]

Heres a guide...

https://sk23.co.uk/magento/magento-2-4-disable-page-builder-for-category-description/

It can also be done for category descriptions - however it's a little more difficult.